# looping through a array of hashes that nested in another array

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I have the following Hash with a array inside a array inside the hash. The inner array is a array of hashes. I am having trouble figuring out how to access them.

```
{"AssetWarrantyResponse"=>
    [{"AssetHeaderData"=>
        {"BUID"=>"11", "ServiceTag"=>"GH3RV12", "ShipDate"=>"2014-06-05T00:00:00", "CountryLookupCode"=>"US", "LocalChannel"=>"45", "CustomerNumber"=>"127963428", "ItemClassCode"=>"RK003", "IsDuplicate"=>false, "MachineDescription"=>"OptiPlex 3020", "OrderNumber"=>"631899941", "ParentServiceTag"=>nil},
      "ProductHeaderData"=>
        {"SystemDescription"=>"OptiPlex 3020", "ProductId"=>"optiplex-3020-desktop", "ProductFamily"=>"Desktops & All-in-Ones", "LOB"=>"OptiPlex", "LOBFriendlyName"=>"OptiPlex"}, 
     "AssetEntitlementData"=>[
        {"StartDate"=>"2022-06-07T00:00:00", "EndDate"=>"2022-06-08T00:00:00", "ServiceLevelDescription"=>"Dell", "ServiceLevelCode"=>"DL", "ServiceLevelGroup"=>11, "EntitlementType"=>"INITIAL", "ServiceProvider"=>"DELL", "ItemNumber"=>"999-0036"}, 
        {"StartDate"=>"2014-06-05T00:00:00", "EndDate"=>"2022-06-05T23:59:59", "ServiceLevelDescription"=>"Dell Digitial Delivery", "ServiceLevelCode"=>"D", "ServiceLevelGroup"=>11, "EntitlementType"=>"INITIAL", "ServiceProvider"=>"DELL", "ItemNumber"=>"422-0052"}, 
        {"StartDate"=>"2015-06-06T00:00:00", "EndDate"=>"2017-06-05T23:59:59", "ServiceLevelDescription"=>"Next Business Day Onsite", "ServiceLevelCode"=>"ND", "ServiceLevelGroup"=>5, "EntitlementType"=>"EXTENDED", "ServiceProvider"=>"UNY", "ItemNumber"=>"939-7368"}, 
        {"StartDate"=>"2015-06-06T00:00:00", "EndDate"=>"2017-06-05T23:59:59", "ServiceLevelDescription"=>"ProSupport", "ServiceLevelCode"=>"TS", "ServiceLevelGroup"=>8, "EntitlementType"=>"EXTENDED", "ServiceProvider"=>"DELL", "ItemNumber"=>"939-7738"},
        {"StartDate"=>"2014-06-05T00:00:00", "EndDate"=>"2015-06-05T23:59:59", "ServiceLevelDescription"=>"Next Business Day Onsite", "ServiceLevelCode"=>"ND", "ServiceLevelGroup"=>5, "EntitlementType"=>"INITIAL", "ServiceProvider"=>"UNY", "ItemNumber"=>"939-6888"}, 
        {"StartDate"=>"2014-06-05T00:00:00", "EndDate"=>"2015-06-05T23:59:59", "ServiceLevelDescription"=>"ProSupport", "ServiceLevelCode"=>"TS", "ServiceLevelGroup"=>8, "EntitlementType"=>"INITIAL", "ServiceProvider"=>"DELL", "ItemNumber"=>"939-7718"}, 
        {"StartDate"=>"2014-06-05T00:00:00", "EndDate"=>"2022-06-08T23:59:59", "ServiceLevelDescription"=>"Dell Digitial Delivery", "ServiceLevelCode"=>"D", "ServiceLevelGroup"=>11, "EntitlementType"=>"INITIAL", "ServiceProvider"=>"DELL", "ItemNumber"=>"422-0008"}, 
        {"StartDate"=>"2014-06-05T00:00:00", "EndDate"=>"2022-06-08T23:59:59", "ServiceLevelDescription"=>"Dell Digitial Delivery", "ServiceLevelCode"=>"D", "ServiceLevelGroup"=>11, "EntitlementType"=>"INITIAL", "ServiceProvider"=>"DELL", "ItemNumber"=>"421-9491"}, 
        {"StartDate"=>"2014-06-05T00:00:00", "EndDate"=>"2022-06-08T23:59:59", "ServiceLevelDescription"=>"Dell Digitial Delivery", "ServiceLevelCode"=>"D", "ServiceLevelGroup"=>11, "EntitlementType"=>"INITIAL", "ServiceProvider"=>"DELL", "ItemNumber"=>"421-9982"}
    ]}
], 
"InvalidFormatAssets"=>{"BadAssets"=>[]}, "InvalidBILAssets"=>{"BadAssets"=>[]}, "ExcessTags"=>{"BadAssets"=>[]}, "AdditionalInformation"=>nil}
```

The following code returns the full array of hashed instead of looping through the hashes.

```
@hash['AssetWarrantyResponse'][0]['AssetEntitlementData'].each do |k| k['StartDate'] end
```

returns:

```
[{"StartDate"=>"2022-06-07T00:00:00", "EndDate"=>"2022-06-08T00:00:00", "ServiceLevelDescription"=>"Dell", "ServiceLevelCode"=>"DL", "ServiceLevelGroup"=>11, "EntitlementType"=>"INITIAL", "ServiceProvider"=>"DELL", "ItemNumber"=>"999-0036"}, {"StartDate"=>"2014-06-05T00:00:00", "EndDate"=>"2022-06-05T23:59:59", "ServiceLevelDescription"=>"Dell Digitial Delivery", "ServiceLevelCode"=>"D", "ServiceLevelGroup"=>11, "EntitlementType"=>"INITIAL", "ServiceProvider"=>"DELL", "ItemNumber"=>"422-0052"}, {"StartDate"=>"2015-06-06T00:00:00", "EndDate"=>"2017-06-05T23:59:59", "ServiceLevelDescription"=>"Next Business Day Onsite", "ServiceLevelCode"=>"ND", "ServiceLevelGroup"=>5, "EntitlementType"=>"EXTENDED", "ServiceProvider"=>"UNY", "ItemNumber"=>"939-7368"}, {"StartDate"=>"2015-06-06T00:00:00", "EndDate"=>"2017-06-05T23:59:59", "ServiceLevelDescription"=>"ProSupport", "ServiceLevelCode"=>"TS", "ServiceLevelGroup"=>8, "EntitlementType"=>"EXTENDED", "ServiceProvider"=>"DELL", "ItemNumber"=>"939-7738"}, {"StartDate"=>"2014-06-05T00:00:00", "EndDate"=>"2015-06-05T23:59:59", "ServiceLevelDescription"=>"Next Business Day Onsite", "ServiceLevelCode"=>"ND", "ServiceLevelGroup"=>5, "EntitlementType"=>"INITIAL", "ServiceProvider"=>"UNY", "ItemNumber"=>"939-6888"}, {"StartDate"=>"2014-06-05T00:00:00", "EndDate"=>"2015-06-05T23:59:59", "ServiceLevelDescription"=>"ProSupport", "ServiceLevelCode"=>"TS", "ServiceLevelGroup"=>8, "EntitlementType"=>"INITIAL", "ServiceProvider"=>"DELL", "ItemNumber"=>"939-7718"}, {"StartDate"=>"2014-06-05T00:00:00", "EndDate"=>"2022-06-08T23:59:59", "ServiceLevelDescription"=>"Dell Digitial Delivery", "ServiceLevelCode"=>"D", "ServiceLevelGroup"=>11, "EntitlementType"=>"INITIAL", "ServiceProvider"=>"DELL", "ItemNumber"=>"422-0008"}, {"StartDate"=>"2014-06-05T00:00:00", "EndDate"=>"2022-06-08T23:59:59", "ServiceLevelDescription"=>"Dell Digitial Delivery", "ServiceLevelCode"=>"D", "ServiceLevelGroup"=>11, "EntitlementType"=>"INITIAL", "ServiceProvider"=>"DELL", "ItemNumber"=>"421-9491"}, {"StartDate"=>"2014-06-05T00:00:00", "EndDate"=>"2022-06-08T23:59:59", "ServiceLevelDescription"=>"Dell Digitial Delivery", "ServiceLevelCode"=>"D", "ServiceLevelGroup"=>11, "EntitlementType"=>"INITIAL", "ServiceProvider"=>"DELL", "ItemNumber"=>"421-9982"}]
```

Could someone point me in the right direction? I want to loop through each hash.

Comment: If you were looking to print the start date then just simply add ``puts`` behind ``k['StartDate']``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array#each returns the original array. In calling `each` with a block on the `"AssetEntitlementData"`, you'll call the block on each hash in the array, and then return the original array. If you're trying to return an array of `"StartDate"` values, try this:

```
@hash['AssetWarrantyResponse'][0]['AssetEntitlementData'].map do |h| 
  h['StartDate']
end
```

Array#map will return an array with the result of calling the block on each element.